# html element innerHtml change with session and server code

Tags: meteor

This webApp has a header which displays a short message based on user interaction by using session in order to make it reactive.  I would like to give the server the **priority** to display its own message it it has one.
Like if server.message is "" then use client session else use server message.
Should I use global helper? or How can go about it? Thanks.

```js
Template.header.helpers({
  headerLabel: function(){
    return Session.get('taskSelected');
  }
});
```

```html
<template name="header">
  <h1>
    <button class="col-xs-2 mainMenu" type="button">&#9776;</button>
  </h1>
  <h3>
    <label class="col-xs-8 text-center">
      {{#if headerLabel}}
        {{headerLabel}}
      {{else}}
        Select an item
      {{/if}}
    </label>
  </h3>
  <h1>
    <button class="col-xs-2" type="button">&#8942;</button>
  </h1>
</template>


Template.mainMenu.events({
  'click .menuItem': function (event) {

    Session.set('taskSelected', this.menuItem);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do this with reactive variables:

```
Template.header.onCreated( function() {
    this.message = new ReactiveVar( "" );
    Meteor.call('serverMessageMethod', function(error, results) {
        if( error || !results ) {
          Template.instance().message.set(Session.get("yourVariable");
        } else {
          Template.instance().message.set(results);
        }
    });
});

Template.header.helpers({
    message() {
      return Template.instance().message.get();
    }
});
```

You'll have to create the server method to see if there's a message, but other than that this should work.

Comment: message(){return Template.instance().message.get();}  is not supported by current javaScript version.